# Why the class variables does not stores values in php class?

Tags: php, class

I just started study of class and object in php. I have a very small program which is as follows.

```
<?PHP
class GetUserPermissions 
{
public $tab1;
public $tab2;
public $tab3;
public $tab4;

public function setMainPagePermissions()
{
    try
    {                   
        $this->SetPermissionsSelection(1,0,5,0);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function SetPermissionsSelection($a,$b,$c,$d)
{       
    $this->$tab1=$a;
    $this->$tab2=$b;
    $this->$tab3=$c;
    $this->$tab4=$d;
}

 public function gettab1Status()
 {
    return $this->$tab1;
 }
  public function gettab2Status()
  {
  return $this->$tab2;

}
public function gettab3Status()
{
    return $this->$tab3;

}
public function gettab4Status()
{
    return $this->$tab4;
}

}

$test=new GetUserPermissions();
$test->setMainPagePermissions();

echo "<br>value 1 : ".$test->gettab1Status();
echo "<br>value 2 : ".$test->gettab2Status();
echo "<br>value 3 : ".$test->gettab3Status();
echo "<br>value 4 : ".$test->gettab4Status();
?>
```

In this its not prints the values of the class member variables.

Comment: One general hint: put `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` on top of your scripts. That will let you know when you are trying to use non-existing variables.

Comment: what is the point of wrapping `$this->SetPremissionsSelection` into a `try/catch` block when the method does not throw anything that could be catched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax problem. In PHP, you access the class members with `$this->foo`, not `$this->$foo.` The latter uses the $foo variable's value to get the member.

Answer (score 2):

Remove dollars when accessing fields with `$this->field`

```
$this->tab1=$a;
$this->tab2=$b;
$this->tab3=$c;
$this->tab4=$d;
```